# Configuration 'compile' is obsolete. Giving errors after replacing with implementation

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm running an existing project, just need a bit help in updating app level build.gradle of an existing project. When I replace the keyword compile with implementation, it does not work for me. Moreover, I am using "gradle-6.1.1-all.zip" in gradle-wrapper.properties and using classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0' in the other build.gradle. And how to replace the other firebase dependencies as well

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':realm')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-lock')
    compile project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':realm')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')

    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
}
```

Here are the errors on terminal

```
problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-lock'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-lock:classpath'.
   > Could not download gradle-core-1.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:1.3.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/1.3.1/gradle-core-1.3.1.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/1.3.1/gradle-core-1.3.1.jar'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download lint-24.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint:24.3.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/24.3.1/lint-24.3.1.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/24.3.1/lint-24.3.1.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download dvlib-24.3.1.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:24.3.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/dvlib/24.3.1/dvlib-24.3.1.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/dvlib/24.3.1/dvlib-24.3.1.jar'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download common-24.3.1.jar (com.android.tools:common:24.3.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/24.3.1/common-24.3.1.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/24.3.1/common-24.3.1.jar'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.48)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.48)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar'.
            > No such host is known (jcenter.bintray.com)
   > Could not download asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar (org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.0.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.0.3/asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.0.3/asm-analysis-5.0.3.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download asm-tree-5.0.3.jar (org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.3/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.3/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download asm-5.0.3.jar (org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download jack-api-0.9.0.jar (com.android.tools.jack:jack-api:0.9.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jack/jack-api/0.9.0/jack-api-0.9.0.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jack/jack-api/0.9.0/jack-api-0.9.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download jill-api-0.9.0.jar (com.android.tools.jill:jill-api:0.9.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jill/jill-api/0.9.0/jill-api-0.9.0.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jill/jill-api/0.9.0/jill-api-0.9.0.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download ecj-4.4.2.jar (org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:4.4.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.4.2/ecj-4.4.2.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.4.2/ecj-4.4.2.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
   > Could not download proguard-base-5.2.1.jar (net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:5.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/5.2.1/proguard-base-5.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/5.2.1/proguard-base-5.2.1.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com
```

Comment: Try using `api` instead of `compile`.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is trying to access files from jcenter but without success. I don't think it's related to gradle or the use of api/implementation (versus compilation)

Do you access to an URL provided in your logs? I advise you to check your connection status / proxy status / … or just retry. It should work.

Comment: Alright, but now it's also giving build errors on these lines:

Comment: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.